# What are the uses of 'package' keyword in DROOLS?

Tags: java, package, drools, drools-flow

In my scenario, we have multiple rule files and we ensure with proper naming convention that every rule name is different, even if they are in different folders, files.

We use a common package name in all the drl files.

Now even if I remove the package name it is working fine(test cases I have checked).

So now I am confused on why and What all are the uses of 'package' keyword.

I already understand that it is much like package in java and used so that we can have same name rules, declared type and imports in different packages.
So, do we also need this if we already ensure that everything we write will have a unique name?

Answer (score 1):

DRL packages create different namespaces for rules.

DRL packages also permit an access of Java classes without an import statement if the DRL package is the same as the Java package.

You don't need to use packages in DRL, but I recommend to use it, even if it is all in a single package. Who knows what tomorrow will bring?